# Update database column during the reading of rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update, sqldatareader

I need to change a column value in the table of my database every time I read a row. Specifically, after the reading of the row I must set the column SENT=1 (by default, before the reading, the value is 0).

My code is:

```
var sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM detector_output WHERE SENT=0";
var Command = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, connection);
MySqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var ident = reader.GetString(0);
    var SENSOR_TYPE = reader.GetString(1);
    var MSG_NAME = reader.GetString(2);
    var DATA_NAME = reader.GetString(3);
    var VALUE = reader.GetString(4);
    var TIMESTAMP = reader.GetString(5);

    var connectionUP = new MySqlConnection(cs);
    connectionUP.Open();
    var sqlCommandUPDATE = "UPDATE detector_output SET SENT=1 WHERE ID=ident";
    var CommandUpdate = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommandUPDATE, connectionUP);
    CommandUpdate.ExecuteReader();
```

The error that I have encountered is:

> unknown column 'ident' in where clause ...

Comment: Is there any reason why you're performing a SELECT on all available rows and then updating individually as they're processed by your application? Have you considered the implications of your processing throwing an error halfway through processing or the database being unavailable during an attempt to update the row?

Comment: Yes, the access to the table of database is done by 3 different processes (applications). I read every 5 minutes the db and I select only the rows not yet read (with the value of column SENT=0). After that, I flag the new row setting SENT=1 (with update command) in order to not read it later...

Comment: How are you handling volatility or race conditions? What if process A has selected the data but has only updated 1/3rd of the rows when process B is ready to capture and process data?

Comment: I write only few data (only alert event...) that can happens for example 1 time in a day...so I think that I have not problem of volatility or race conditions. I only need to select the data not SENT (with SENT=0) and set this column value to 1 after sending the data

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `ident` as a variable in your query. You defined it as `ID=ident` that's why your provider confuse and it thinks you *actually* try to filter where your `ID` column value is equal to `ident` column value.

What if `ident` is a character? Then, it would be defined as `ID = 'ident'`, isn't it?

Define a parameter for it and later, add it's value.

```
var sqlCommandUPDATE = "UPDATE detector_output SET SENT=1 WHERE ID = @ident";
var CommandUpdate = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommandUPDATE, connectionUP);
CommandUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ident", ident);
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and readers.

Comment: I don't need to add value for column ident but I need to update SENT column to 1 when I have a ident=ID (ID is the primary key of my table)